# MotionLayout animation not working properly inside RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-motionlayout

I use this library [StackExpandable](https://github.com/fabiosassu/StackExpandableView) to add an Expand/Collapse cardViews as a recyclerview item. Expand/Collapse works fine. But the issue I am facing is that when I expand two items and while scrolling, any item goes out of the screen and comes back, stacked card appears as a normal card. I have tried tracking the expand/collapse states. But, this issue is still there. Here's the video of the issue I am facing: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MEbMvQXRn9jDNTpbDgzQFtBF78LyczrL/view?usp=sharing
Please let me know figure out whats happening to the Recyclerview item when it goes out of the screen and how can it be prevented?

This is the RecyclerView item_layout:

```
<it.fabiosassu.stackexpandableview.StackExpandableView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/verticalStackedCardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:shownElements="3"/>
```

Comment: You probably have to set the state of the MotionLayout during bind. 
It may require you to wrap that in a view.post() because the state may not stick until it attached.
capturing and setting the state is the way to go.

Comment: thanks for ur comment. But, I didn't get ur point. Could u elaborate more on this..?

Comment: It is difficult to know how much background you have and have know knowledge of StackExpandable.
To achieve its performance Recycler view works by recycling the "view" in this case the MotionLayout instances.  Typically RecyclerView creates about 3 more MotionLayout instances than fit on the screen.  So when a view (in this case MotionLayout) goes off screen it looses its state as it is reused.  It is up to the programmer to capture and reload the state as the view is about to be reused.

Comment: @hoford I am keeping the track of whether the layout is collapsed or not. But this issue happens without calling onBindViewHolder. It just happens

Comment: This is just not enough information to understand what is wrong.

Comment: @JayeshBabu Hi, have you found the solution? I got this same issue